# Angular 2.0 deep-linking does not work. Same from the address bar

Tags: node.js, angular, routes, deep-linking

Everything works OK when I build and navigate links in the app but typing in the address bar does not! 
Eventually I want to be able to send a link to a specific app page/path via email and I am not sure how to accomplish that.

I have followed the [angular router guide documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html). Correctly I think...

I'm using NodeJS (with express) and in the server I have redirected all traffic to the app root.

```
app.get("*", function(req, res) {
    console.error("in get *")
    res.redirect("/");
});
```

In my index.html I have set base

```
<base href="/">
```

I have my client routs/paths set as follows

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'vendor/registration', component: VendorRegistrationComponent },
  { path: 'vendors', component: VendorListComponent },
  { path: '',  redirectTo: 'vendor/registration', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }    
];
```

If I type `http://localhost:8080/vendors` in the browser address bar I get to `http://localhost:8080/vendor/registration` which kind of makes sense because that's where the server tells the browser to redirect to.

How then should I deep link to my app?

Edit. 
The Angular tutorial - "TOUR OF HEROES" - also exhibits the same behavior. i.e. entering urls in the browser's address bar directly does not work. The app shows a "loading..." text and does not route to the controller.

Comment: What do you mean by deep linking? What did you expect to get?

Comment: What I want is to be able to send users an email link such as http://www.example.com/vendors and for the right view/controller to display (rather than the root element)

Comment: What is your code for `app.get('/', function (req, res) { /* what's here */ })`

Comment: What do you mean with "because that's where the server tells the browser to redirect to." Why does the server redirect to that URL?

Comment: @ibdehold - I dont have a specific handler for '/'. I have the catchall '*' I have written above

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer - any request coming to the server (by click a link in an email OR typing in the address bar) is redirected to the client app via the catch-all handler app.get("*",

Comment: but then your `<base>` should probably be `<base href="/vendor/registration">` and you path for the first route `''`. Mixing server and client path won't fly.

Comment: If I change <base> and the path for the first route as you have written, would users clicking a link in an email: http://www.example.com/vendors reach the relevant component (VendorListComponent)?

Comment: As you've said, it's the server redirecting to `/`, and Angular route configuration always redirects `/` to `/vendor/registration`. Setting `<base href="/vendor/registration">` wouldn't change the situation. You'll need such an entry point (for ex: `/` at the Angular side) so that the Angular router will be able to render the requested path using its router.

Comment: Furthermore, if you're using Angular Router 3.4.8, nothing will work - because they merged such a pull request changed the router functionality non backwards-compatible. If that's the case, revert back to Angular Router 3.4.7 or wait until 3.4.9 gets released. You can have detailed information on this link: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14588

Comment: Just run "ng -v". All @angular modules are 2.4.7 except @angular/router which is 3.4.7, so no luck here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response at your question is explicitly describe in the [angular2 documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/deployment.html#!#fallback)

Comment: Thanks. For some reason this is not referenced or mentioned in [link](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html). 
Moreover, I actually tried that but referenced the wrong `index.html`, instead of the one in `/dist` folder I reference the one in the `/src` folder.

Answer (score 3):

Generally you would not need to redirect on the server since all of your routing is handled by the angular router on the client.

Instead make your catch-all express route simply always serve your `index.html` for all requested urls. When the client app bootstraps, angular will take care of routing to the appropriate component based on the requested url. Make sure to keep your `<base href="/">` tag so that angular can be aware of what part of the url is routed.

```
const path = require('path');

app.get("*", function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/path/to/your/index.html'));
});
```

Comment: This finally worked for me with the following **important note**: The `index.html` file that is sent to the client should be the one located in the `/dist` folder rather than the one in the original `/src` folder. (at least for node+express projects with default setup)
`var indexFile = path.join(__dirname, "dist/index.html");res.sendFile(indexFile);`